# Announcing Winter Bash 2015

Tags: discussion

### [English](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/12/announcing-winter-bash-2015)

Another calendar year is ending, which can mean only one thing. It's time once again for the event that brings joy to all (with a slight helping of dismay for our friends in the southern hemisphere1): Winter Bash!

[image: Ou... Summer Bash pra muitos de vocês]

Starting now and going until the end of the day on Jan. 3, 2016, you'll once again be able to earn and show off hats for all sorts of things you're already doing across the Stack Exchange network. As in previous years, we're rolling out an all-new array of hats for this year's event. (For those who are wondering, this is entirely because we on the SE team love our communities and think you deserve the best, and not at all because we forget where we store the old hats every year.)

That means we owe another big thank you to amazing freelance designer [Elias Stein](http://www.eliasstein.com), who deftly handled the conversion of all hats from crazy vague concepts into beautiful digital reality for the third year in a row, and our very own unicorn lord [balpha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/24/balpha), who once again worked tirelessly behind the scenes to perfect the hat distribution process.

Hats, for those who don't know, are sort of like badges, but better, because you can "wear" hats on your avatar, displaying them wherever your avatar appears, network-wide! (And thanks to a labor of love by [Brian Nickel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/23142/brian-nickel), that includes the iOS app this year!) The triggers for hats are a little different than the triggers for badges; to find out what you have to do to get some headpieces, check out the Winter Bash [mini-site](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com). There are 28 total hats you can earn over the next few weeks… that we're telling you about. How many secret hats are there this year, you ask? You're on your own. We're not spilling the beanies.

After you've earned some hats, you can visit your profile on any site to choose the hat you want to wear (or simply admire your own personal hat rack). Just click on the bobble hat adorning your badges section to bring up a dialog.

[image: Gorro no verão é uma opção arriscada]

(No, you can't wear the bobble hat yourself. Your badges would get cold!)

[image: Nem tudo que é um chapéu tem que ser um chapéu mesmo, certo?]

Once you've picked a hat, you can resize and reposition it in the selection window to suit your avatar. Last year's example image for this was so perfect that it just has to be reused:

[image: Shog9: Caçador de Vampiros]

Finally, you don't need to worry about tracking all this stuff yourself. You'll get notifications about new hats via a special, Winter-Bash-only top bar inbox: [image: É bastante reputação, hein...]

Of course, if you think all this is weird and don't want any part of it, that's okay, we won't judge you (much). You can opt out of the event by clicking on the snowflake icon in the top bar—[image: neve? Em pleno verão???]—and then the "I hate hats" link at the bottom left of the box that pops up. (NB: the reverse is true on Stack Overflow; fans of hats on SO will have to go through the same procedure but click a link to opt in at the end.) You're welcome to change your mind about wanting hats at any time during the event.

Just remember, all the hats will vanish again after three weeks. Now go! Other people out there are already working on their degrees2!

[Tradução por: Eu mesmo http://poorlydrawnlines.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/cool-hat.png](http://www.poorlydrawnlines.com)

1: *As in the past, tradition defeated accuracy in the naming decision. Hopefully some of our summertime audience will be at least partially mollified by the fact that the Winter Bash site will be available in Portuguese, Spanish, Japanese and Russian this year, thanks to the efforts of our international Community Managers*.

2: *The University of Winter Bash has not been accredited by any organization recognized by the Council for Higher Education Accreditation or the United States Department of Education. Yet.*

---

### [Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4670/come%C3%A7ou-o-winter-bash-2015)

by [@Gabe](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/users/166/gabe?tab=profile)

Mais um fim de ano se aproxima, e com isso o evento que espalha alegria e felicidade por todo o mundo (e um pouquinho de desgosto em quem mora abaixo do Equador<sup>1</sup>): **Winter Bash!**

[image: Ou... Summer Bash pra muitos de vocês]

De hoje até o dia 3 de Janeiro de 2016, você vai poder ganhar vários chapéus diferentes e exibí-los para o mundo todo. Basta continuar usando o site, fazendo as mesmas coisas que já vinha fazendo antes. Assim como nos anos anteriores, temos uma coleção totalmente nova de chapéus. (Isso é porque nós amamos todos vocês e acreditamos que vocês sempre merecem o melhor, e não porque esquecemos de salvar a lista do ano passado… Obviamente). Então palmas para o nosso designer freelance [Elias Stein](http://www.eliasstein.com), que usou seu talento para converter todas as nossas ideias em belos chapéus digitais, pelo terceiro ano consecutivo , e também para o *Senhor dos Unicórnios* - o primeiro e único [balpha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/24/balpha)! Mais uma vez ele trabalhou incansavelmente para garantir que nimguém ficaria sem seus chapéus.

Pra quem não sabe como funciona, os chapéus são como medalhas, só que **melhores**, já que você pode usar os chapéus no seu avatar, e exibí-los em todos os lugares da rede onde sua foto aparece! (E graças ao [Brian Nickel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/23142/brian-nickel), esse ano o aplicativo iOS também faz parte da festa!) Os requisitos para ganhar um chapéu são um pouco diferentes dos requisitos para medalhas. Se quiser saber como conseguir os seus, dê uma olhada no [mini-site do Winter Bash](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com). No total são 28 chapéus…oficialmente. Será que existem chapéus secretos? Quantos são? Como ganhá-los?
Sei lá… vocês vão ter que descobrir sozinhos!

Quando você quiser usar seus chapéus, basta acessar o seu perfil, em qualquer site da rede, e escolher um chapéu para vestir (ou admirá-los na sua estante). É só clicar no gorro em cima da das suas medalhas.

[image: Gorro no verão é uma opção arriscada]

(O gorro é para deixar suas medalhas aquecidas então não, você não pode usá-lo)

[image: Nem tudo que é um chapéu tem que ser um chapéu mesmo, certo?]

Depois de escolher um chapéu para usar, você pode escolher o tamanho e posição que melhor se encaixe no seu avatar. O exemplo do ano passado é perfeito demais para não ser usado de novo:

[image: Shog9: Caçador de Vampiros]

Você vai ver uma nova notificação, especial para o Winter Bash, sempre que ganhar um chapéu novo, então é fácil saber quando você pode dar uma atualizada na aparência: [image: É bastante reputação, hein...].

E se você acha que esse negócio todo não serve pra nada, sem problema! Clique no floco de neve na barra superior para escolher não participar do evento —[image: neve? Em pleno verão???]— e depois no link que diz “Eu odeio chapéus” no rodapé da janela. (No Stack Overflow em Inglês, funciona ao contrário. Você precisa fazer a mesma coisa mas para **participar** do evento). Sempre lembrando que você pode mudar de ideia a qualquer momento e mudar sua opção.

Não se esqueça também que os chapéus vão desaparecer em três semanas, então não perca tempo! Tem gente que já tá correndo atrás do diploma<sup>2</sup>!

[image: Tradução por: Eu mesmo]

1: *Como em anos anteriores, a tradição venceu ao nomear o evento. Esperamos que todos vocês que estão no verão sintam algum conforto no fato de que, esse ano, o Winter Bash também está acontecendo em Português, Espanhol, Japonês e Russo, graças ao trabalho dos nossos Gerentes de Comunidades internacionais.*

2: *A Universidade Winter Bash não é reconhecida por nenhum órgão de educação superior, em lugar nenhum… **Ainda**.*

Comment: [Winter Bash 2015 Secret Hats](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270789/winter-bash-2015-secret-hats)