# Winter Bash 2016

Tags: discussion

### Português

No ano que passou já tivemos este evento onde podemos ganhar chapéus para comemorar esta época do final ano: [Announcing Winter Bash 2015](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214/announcing-winter-bash-2015).

[image]

O Winter Bash começa no dia 19 de dezembro deste ano e vai até o dia 8 de janeiro do ano que vem.

O ranking e os chapéus conquistados pelos utilizadores poderão ser acompanhados através da [página do Winter Bash 2016](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/).

---

### English

We will once again be able to earn and show off hats for all sorts of things like in last year: [Announcing Winter Bash 2015](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214/announcing-winter-bash-2015).

This year's event will run from December 19th to January 8th. More information on this and individual hat-earning progress will eventually be [posted here](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Sabem quem é o senhor do chapéu? ;)

Comment: Passei algumas vezes por uma Pessoa parecida na Brasileira do Chiado em Lisboa.